# Error to Create symbolic binary link

Tags: linux, symlink, vi

I want to create a symbolic link for vi to see this program when calling 
from console run vim:

```
ln -s /usr/bin/vi /usr/bin/vim`
ln: failure to create symbolic link «/ usr / bin / vim»: The file already exists
```

how can I do it so I saw it point to vim

Comment: `ls -l /usr/bin/vim` show you what? It seems that this link ALREADY exists or it is a specific `no compat` link to `vi`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution:

You can force to remove the destination file using -f (Test before changing anything!)

`ln -sf /usr/bin/vi /usr/bin/vim`

Works for me!

### Example:

```
[root@vvek-workstation grep]# ln -ss ./vi ./vim 
ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘./vim’: File exists
[root@vvek-workstation grep]# ln -sf ./vi ./vim 
[root@vvek-workstation grep]# ls -lart
total 0
drwxr-xr-x. 9 root root 228 Mar 20 15:20 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   0 Mar 20 16:00 vi
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   4 Mar 20 16:00 vim -> ./vi
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  27 Mar 20 16:00 .
```

Comment: and to remove the symbolic link without deleting vim ??

Comment: ln -sf /usr/bin/vim /usr/bin/vi  perfect but i need to remove the symbolic link without deleting vim ??

Answer (score 1):

Given your original tag of CentOS, I'll assume that you have an `/etc/profile.d/vim.sh` file that sets up an alias:

```
alias vi >/dev/null 2>&1 || alias vi=vim
```

If you want to run `vi` when you enter `vim`, I'd suggest adding to your own `~/.bashrc`:

```
unalias vi
alias vim=vi
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you already have `/usr/bin/vim`, you cannot have another file of the same name in that directory. However, `/usr/bin` is (usually) not the only location checked for executables.

Run `echo $PATH` to see the list of directories that is checked, left to right. Hopefully, you'll have locations like `/home/(username)/bin` or `/usr/local/bin` in there. In that case,

```
ln -s /usr/bin/vi /usr/local/bin/vim
```

will override the default vim for all users. (They can still call `/usr/bin/vim` to get the original.)